# Counting Policy Ages with a Query in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing insurance policies (let's call it POLICIES) in one field, along with the policies off of which they were renewed in another field:

```
POLICY_ID | PRIOR_POLICY_ID
===========================
ABC       |
ABD       |   ABC
AFP       |
ANR       |   ABD
BRC       |   AFP
FKZ       |
```

I would like to write a query to count the total number of prior policies for each policy, with the result looking like this:

```
POLICY_ID | NUM_PRIOR_POLICIES
==============================
ABC       |   0
ABD       |   1
AFP       |   0
ANR       |   2
BRC       |   1
FKZ       |   0
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select p.policy_id, 0 as num_priors
      from policies p
      where prior_policy_id is null
      union all
      select p.policy_id, 1 + cte.num_priors
      from cte join
           policies p
           on p.prior_policy_id = cte.policy_id
)
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14620) is a SQL Fiddle showing it working.

Comment: I got this answer to work too, although my actual data set is a little bit more complicated in that 5 fields actually compose the "POLICY_ID". But I was able to join them to get it to work. Also, thanks for the SQL Fiddle link. I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @GeneDan . . . As the OP you have every right to accept whichever answer you think is better.  I'm curious why you chose essentially the same answer posted many minutes after mine.

Comment: I tried the answers in reverse order when I refreshed the page. I was going to check both but I guess you can only pick one (kinda new to this). I'll check this one because it has the SQL Fiddle link, I thought it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ( POLICY_ID char(3), PRIOR_POLICY_ID char(3) );

INSERT @data VALUES
  ('ABC',NULL ),('ABD','ABC'),('AFP',NULL ),
  ('ANR','ABD'),('BRC','AFP'),('FKZ',NULL );

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT POLICY_ID, 0 AS NUM_PRIOR_POLICIES
  FROM @data
  WHERE PRIOR_POLICY_ID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.POLICY_ID, NUM_PRIOR_POLICIES + 1
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN @data d
    ON (c.POLICY_ID = d.PRIOR_POLICY_ID)
)
SELECT POLICY_ID, NUM_PRIOR_POLICIES
FROM cte
ORDER BY POLICY_ID
```